# Providing an alias with a arguement without it evaluating to two strings

Tags: bash, scripting, solaris

Hi I have added this alias to my .bashrc:

```
alias awrco='svn co https://x.x.com/x/x/x/projects/'
```

I want to be able to type at the command line:

```
awcro project1/src/
```

and it evaluate to:

```
svn co https://x.x.com/x/x/x/projects/project1/src
```

Is this possible? At the minute the command obviously evaluates to:

```
svn co https://x.x.com/x/x/x/projects/ project1/src    <--- note the space between projects and project1.
```

I have tried searching for this problem but to no avail.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a function instead:

```
function awrco() { svn co https://x.x.com/x/x/x/projects/"$@" ;}
```